# Exception caught by image resource service Cannot open file, path = 'test'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use AssetImage to define a default image for contacts that don't have images defined and saved in the database, but the following message appears in the debug console: Exception caught by image resource service The following FileSystemException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Cannot open file, path = 'test' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2Uf1.png)

The AssetImage widget was replaced by ImageAsset and NetworkImage, but the same difficulty persisted and the default image did not appear
[Image Pubspec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEIcN.png)

My code:

```
Widget cardContacts(BuildContext context, int index) {
return GestureDetector(
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 80,
          width: 80,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: listContacts[index].img != null
                    ? FileImage(
                        File(listContacts[index].img!),
                      )
                    : const AssetImage('assets/imgs/img.png')
                        as ImageProvider,
                fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
        ),
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
        ),
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(listContacts[index].name!),
            Text(listContacts[index].email!),
            Text(listContacts[index].phone!),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: you're trying to open a file named 'test' and the file doesn't exists, share your code.

Comment: You need to share the code you are using the call the file. You can also try flutter clean and the flutter pub get. Close your IDE and then open it up again. If your paths are correct it should work.

Comment: All paths are correct, including the image column itself in the database, but even so the default image does not appear